# keychain problem

Tags: iphone, app-store, keychain, application-loader

i am uploading a application on appstore,when i upload the build in Applicationloader, i face an error given as below. please give me the detail to solve this problem.
ERROR --
"Application failed codesign verification. The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate."

Answer (score 0):

So... are you asking what that error message means? It means you need a valid distribution certificate signed by Apple that you can use to sign your binary. You can get that by logging into the iOS Dev Center and using the iOS Provisioning Portal to create the certificate.

Comment: To solve the issue i just try to create a new certificate. But i got a new problem in the process of creating a new certificate that is as given "Generating a Certificate Signing Request go to next step to Submitting a Certificate Signing Request For Approval,In this step After creating a CSR, log in to the iOS Provisioning Portal and navigate to ‘Certificates’ -> ‘Distribution’ and click the ‘Add Certificate’ button. But still there is no button like "Add Certificate" display on my screen.
Please tell me the proper way to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the iOS Provisioning Portal, provisioning menu, distribution tab and be sure that you create and use the certificate with the **'app store' option active**. 
The certificate for uploading to the app store is different to the certificate you use for add-hoc distribution.

Then, install the distribution provisioning profile on xcode, and be sure that you compile your build with that certificate.

Hope this helps.

Comment: To solve the issue i just try to create a new certificate. But i got a new problem in the process of creating a new certificate that is as given "Generating a Certificate Signing Request go to next step to Submitting a Certificate Signing Request For Approval,In this step After creating a CSR, log in to the iOS Provisioning Portal and navigate to ‘Certificates’ -> ‘Distribution’ and click the ‘Add Certificate’ button. But still there is no button like "Add Certificate" display on my screen.
Please tell me the proper way to solve this issue.

Comment: Maybe you should try with another browser, have you tried with safari? sometimes the web does not work very well :(